# Specialised FaultException subclass or FaultException<T>

Tags: c#, wcf, exception, faultexception, faultcontract

I want my WCF service to be able to return some known faults. ie a defined FaultContract

I'm a bit confused as to whether I should be deriving my own `FaultException` subclass, or creating a detail class and using `FaultException<TDetail>`.

There appear to be examples of both scattered about and I just wondered what the general consensus was.

I'm leaning towards deriving, since I think that client code would look cleaner catching `MyException` rather than WCF centric `FaultException<MyExceptionDetail>`, but I don't really have any strong feelings about it.

Comment: Since there is no way for your service to return a derived class of `FaultException`, your choice is clear.

Comment: It would appear you are correct, thanks. I must have found some bad examples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `FaultException` generally for unknown or generic faults, and `FaultException<T>` for typed faults.

Typed faults are more akin to typed exceptions in standard .NET, so they would be the preferred method.

Note that you need to use [fault contracts](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752208.aspx) in your service contract definition, otherwise all exceptions will reach the client as `FaultException`, even if you throw a `FaultException<T>`.